# Integration of HTML 5 charts with communtiy iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, integration, ireport

I am using JasperReport Server 4.5 and iReport 4.5 community edition  and in community edition we do not have any HTML 5 chart library like enterprise edition in iReport.

[HTML 5 Charts](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/advanced-formatting-new-html5-charts)

Is there any way to integrate these HTML 5 charts with community edition iReport?

Answer (score 1):

"iReport Professional version5.0 introduced Jaspersoft’s new HTML5 charting library."

You'll need to buy JasperReports Professional if you want this feature.
https://www.jaspersoft.com/store/jaspersoft-professional-developer-edition

Best Regards.

Comment: the link is dead.